# Why does "pgrep -a" output differ depending on how a file is opened?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 or Kubuntu 18.04

If I open a file via the file manager by right-clicking and choosing gedit to open it and then run `pgrep -a` I get

```
dkb@dkb-ubu1804:~$ pgrep -a gedit
2044 gedit /home/dkb/.bash_aliases
```

On the other hand, if I first open gedit and use the file chooser dialogue to open the same file, all `pgrep -a` shows me is

```
dkb@dkb-ubu1804:~$ pgrep -a gedit
2081 gedit
dkb@dkb-ubu1804:~$
```

The name of the file and the path isn't shown.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `pgrep -a` shows both a program's name and its [command-line arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments), and when you right-click on `/home/dkb/.bash_aliases` and open it with `gedit`, this actually runs `gedit` with `/home/dkb/.bash_aliases` as a command-line argument. This is to say that it is as though you had run the command `gedit /home/dkb/.bash_aliases`. Passing filenames as command-line arguments isn't just for programs you would normally run in a terminal. It is also essential to how opening files in a desktop environment works.

When you run a program to open a file, whether by right-clicking on the file and selecting the program, double-clicking on the file when it is of a MIME type that is configured to open with that particular program, or dragging the file onto a launcher for the program, this causes the program to be run with the filename passed to it as a command-line argument. This works the same way as if you ran `gedit filename` in a terminal window, which also works.

In contrast, opening gedit without an initial file to edit doesn't pass it any command-line arguments. This works the same way as if you ran just `gedit`. **When you *then* open the file in the program, that doesn't change what command-line arguments were passed to it.**

It's possible for a program to attempt to change what command-line arguments will appear to have been passed to it, when programs like `pgrep` check. But this is rarely done, most often as a half-measure to redact sensitive information like passwords. (A better approach is to not convey passwords in command-line arguments.)

The command-line arguments don't represent the state of the program. Instead, they specify how the program was run, or, to put it another way, what it was told to do initially. (They're not the only information a program receives when it's started--programs also have environment variables, a current working directory, and a umask, for example.) Both command-line and graphical editors accept filenames as command-line arguments.

---

For a more complete picture, I should say that the specific *way* command-line arguments are passed to a graphical program run in a desktop environment varies across programs. It is specified in the launcher--that is, the `.desktop` file--that is used to run the program.

To work, a `.desktop` file must specify [an Exec key](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/#exec-variables)<sup>**1**</sup> that gives the command and also--for commands that support being launched to open a file or other resource--a placeholder for arguments. Multiple placeholders are available, but `%U` is common. It is replaced with zero, one, or more URLs or filenames. The `Exec` line in `gedit.desktop` is:

```
Exec=gedit %U
```

<sub><sup>**1**</sup> That link goes to GNOME documentation, but this [also applies](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/#introduction) to KDE and other desktop environments. It is [a freedesktop.org specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).</sub>